# SQL query to combine total of two fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I ought to combine two result fields based on my requirement. For example, below query provides the result as shown. But I need a case statement that states that both 'wind' and 'wind c' are the same, hence combine its total.

```
SELECT result, COUNT(*) AS total from(
SELECT t.Id AS Id,
  CASE 
   WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(AC)) = ' ' THEN AG 
   WHEN LOWER(AC) IS NOT NULL THEN LOWER(AC) 
   ELSE LOWER(AG) 
  END AS result,MaxDate,
FROM [DC_20160601] t
INNER JOIN ( SELECT Id, MAX(DateTime) AS MaxDate
FROM [DC_20160601]
GROUP BY Id) tm
ON t.Id = tm.Id AND t.DateTime = tm.MaxDate)
GROUP BY result
```

Current Result:

```
Result    Total
Wind      1212
Wind c    345
sqrim     321
sqrim mob 123
```

Expected Result:

```
Result      Total
Wind mobile  1557
Sqrim mobile 444
```

Comment: Can I assume that both fields in a given couple fields have the same prefix, and all couples have the different prefix ? For example, `Wind` and `Wind c` have the same prefix `Wind`. Then `Wind` and `Sqrim` are different.

Comment: Check your data. It looks to me that you have different values for AC then you are expecting in the DC_20160601 table. It looks like you might need to be aggregating base on "Wind" and "Sqrim". If that is the case then you need to copy the left side of AC or AG up to the space between.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? Putting `[]` around table names is for SQL-Server.

Comment: Can `LTRIM(RTRIM(AC))` ever result in `' '`? When removing all blanks from left and right, how could you end up with a blank?

Comment: Is it always 'Wind', 'Wind c', 'sqrim' and 'scrim mob'? Or can there be other values? If there can be other values: By which rule do you detect which belong together? Is it always the first word? And is the result always supposed to be first word plus 'mobile'?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first word in a string via `substring_index`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`result`, ' ', 1);
```

Now group by the first word of `result`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`result`, ' ', 1), COUNT(*) AS total from(
SELECT t.Id AS Id,
  CASE 
   WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(AC)) = ' ' THEN AG 
   WHEN LOWER(AC) IS NOT NULL THEN LOWER(AC) 
   ELSE LOWER(AG) 
  END AS result,MaxDate,
FROM [DC_20160601] t
INNER JOIN ( SELECT Id, MAX(DateTime) AS MaxDate
FROM [DC_20160601]
GROUP BY Id) tm
ON t.Id = tm.Id AND t.DateTime = tm.MaxDate)
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(`result`, ' ', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to extract everything before the first space and use this for grouping:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(result, ' ', 1)
```

Otherwise you need to maintain a lookup table to match multiple variations to a single result.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the case statements as an outer query. Assuming that your query returns the Current Result that you posted, here is an example of the needed case statements:

`select
    case 
        when a.result = 'Wind' or a.result = 'Wind c' then 'Wind mobile' 
    else 
        case 
            when a.result = 'sqrim' or a.result = 'sqrim mob' 
            then 'Squirm mobile'
        end 
    end as res,
    sum(total)
from
    (
     SELECT result, COUNT(*) AS total from(
       SELECT t.Id AS Id,
       CASE 
         WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(AC)) = ' ' THEN AG 
         WHEN LOWER(AC) IS NOT NULL THEN LOWER(AC) 
       ELSE LOWER(AG) 
       END AS result,MaxDate,
      FROM [DC_20160601] t
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT Id, MAX(DateTime) AS MaxDate
        FROM [DC_20160601]
        GROUP BY Id) tm
      ON t.Id = tm.Id AND t.DateTime = tm.MaxDate)
      GROUP BY result
    ) a
  group by res`

It would be best to have the values in the case statements specified in a lookup table and to get them from there or you can just add additional ones as case statements if needed but it's not ideal...
Hope this helps!